# Reverse dns how to setup ptr record?

Tags: domain-name-system, ptr-record

For my own mailserver I now have to setup PTR records for the reverse DNS.

My question is in which fields do I put what?
For example my IP address is 192.168.4.4 and domain example.com (with mailserver mail.example.com)

```
Name: ?
Type: PTR
Value: ?
```

Do I also have to update the spf record?

Comment: great, being voted down and no reason given...

Comment: You are downvoted because this question is clearly offtopic. This is a programmers' site. Your question will be soon closed and possibly migrated to Serverfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
62    IN    PTR    mail.mydomain.com.
```

Further you don't have to update the SPF record since its contained in the forward lookup zone. Adding a PTR record happens in the reverse lookup zone (55.234.123.IN-ADDR.ARPA.) thus it not affects the other zone.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse DNS records are configured by your service provider.  This is usually the same people that assign you your static IP addresses.  [EasyDNS](http://support.easydns.com/tutorials/ReverseDNS/structure.php) provides a tutorial that may be useful to you as well.

Comment: In the amateur world maybe but as this site is for professionals lets consider that nearly all of us handle, although not always serve, the DNS for the domains under our control, not the ISPs.

Comment: Let's not bother considering that John. The users of this site vary hugely in their capabilities and skill levels. There are, I am sure, plenty of "amateur" server admins using this site to help them learn and improve their server skills. Robins answer may well point them in the direction they needed.